# How does malloc distinguish between different types that both take up the same space?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

Suppose the following program is run on an x86_64 system:

```
int main() {
    //sizeof(int) == 4
    //sizeof(int*) == 8
    //sizeof(long) == 8

    // I would like 2 distinct memory locations to hold these two integers
    int* mem1 = (int*)malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    mem1[0] = 1;
    mem1[1] = 2;

    //I would like 1 distinct memory location to hold this one long
    long* mem2 = (long*)malloc(1 * sizeof(long));
    mem2[0] = 3;

    free(mem1);
    free(mem2);
    return 0;
}
```

Since `malloc` receives a number of bytes to allocate, both calls to malloc look exactly the same. How does malloc know to actually allocate 16 bytes to store the two integer array and only to allocate 8 bytes for the one long?

Edit for clarity:
Based on the following assumptions, storing these two different arrays will require a different amount of space for each. However, malloc appears to reserve the same amount of space each time in this program. Yet, arrays sizes are correctly determined for arrays of datatypes of different lengths than `long`s.

Can someone help me identify a flaw in this understanding of the memory, or point to something that malloc / libc is doing in the background? Here are the assumptions I'm operating on

- At each memory address on this system, a maximum of one long can be stored in it
- `mem[idx]` refers to the address of mem plus the offset of idx, and that address cannot point to data in the middle of another item in memory (so `mem1[0]` cannot refer to the lower half-word of `mem1` and `mem1[1]` can't then refer to the high word)
- When an array of integers are made, two integers are not packed on this system into one long

Comment: It does no such type distinguishing at all. Thus the reason it returns you a `void*` and requires a *byte* count. The type-distinguishing is *your* job; not `malloc()`'s

Comment: What makes you think that `malloc` allocated 16 bytes for the two integer array?

Comment: Since ints are only 4 bytes, it needs only 8 bytes to store the 2 integer array.  In both cases it allocates 8 bytes and doesn't care about what types you're eventually going to store in it.

Comment: `malloc()` doesn't have a clue. `sizeof()` knows the difference.

Comment: @StephenCanon mem1 would need to be at least 16 bytes to store the two integers without packing them together into one long. I think malloc would have to allocate 16 bytes, otherwise you could not make a list of ints indexed with an offset without unpacking them.

Comment: @David: `malloc` doesn’t *store* anything.  It allocates memory and does nothing else.  It doesn’t dictate how your program goes on to store data in the allocated memory.

Comment: @David With `sizeof (int) == 4`, you need 8 bytes for an array of two `int`s, not 16.

Comment: @abelenky, if both calls return 16 bytes, then does malloc multiply the number of bytes to allocate by 2? That wouldn't work if I wanted an array of 8 characters which would also give an input of 8 bytes to malloc. If I didn't want to pack these characters together into an int or long I would need 64 bytes of data.

Comment: @StephenCanon My assumption is with `mem1[idx]` idx points to an entire long of data that can be stored at the address of mem1 plus the idx. Further, I'm assuming that when malloc is called with an input of 8 bytes it will reserve one address where one long can be stored. When storing a type that is smaller than a long, the data goes in the lower bytes of the memory space and the rest is zeroed. If these assumptions are true then `mem1[1]` should not work because `*(mem + 1)` will refer to the next address which was not reserved by malloc.

Comment: Correction:  Both `malloc` calls allocate 8 bytes, not 16 as I previously wrote.  In the first case, the program treats 8 bytes as a 4-byte `int`, followed by another 4-byte `int`.  In the second case, its a single, 8-byte `long`.

Comment: @abelenky, so C is packing the integers behind the scenes? So when the compiler sees that it's an integer array it doesn't actually read a value from mem + 1 but rather it reads the high 4 bytes of mem?

Comment: I don't know what you mean about "behind the scenes".  It is very upfront about it.  **You asked for 8 bytes, you got 8 bytes.**  What you put in those 8 bytes (1 long, two ints, or 8 chars), is entirely up to *you*.

Comment: @David: Each integer is 4 bytes.  The first one gets stored in bytes 0-3.  The second gets stored in bytes 4-7.  No packing occurs at any point.

Comment: You seem to believe that `long` is the basic unit of memory, and that using less than `sizeof(long)` bytes to store a piece of data constitutes “packing”.  This is incorrect; `char` is the basic unit of memory, not `long`.  On your platform an `int` is stored in four `char`s of memory.

Comment: @StephenCanon Maybe we have a different definition of what packing is, because storing the first int in the first 4 bytes at mem1 and the next int in the next 4 bytes of mem1 is packing. Each item in mem1 should be at a unique memory location so that the values in the array can be indexed. The storage of each memory location is one long. mem1[1] would mean to look at the next memory location, not the higher 4 bytes of mem1.

Comment: @StephenCanon Thanks. That was the problem in my understanding I was looking for. Can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questioner was confused because he didn’t realize that `char` is the basic unit of memory in C.  On his platform, `sizeof(int)` (which is the number of `char`s necessary to store an `int`) is 4.  Thus, to store two `int`s, one needs to allocate `2*sizeof(int)`, or 8 bytes.

In the hypothetical world where `long` is the basic unit of memory (and `sizeof(long) == 8`), storing two `int`s really would require either packing or for 16 bytes to be allocated, but that’s not the way that C works.

Answer (score 7):

> How does malloc distinguish between different types that both take up the same space?

It doesn't.

> Since malloc receives a number of bytes to allocate, both calls to malloc look exactly the same. How does malloc know to actually allocate 16 bytes to store the two integer array and only to allocate 8 bytes for the one long

It can only use the size that you pass it as its argument. Your example and/or understanding is flawed, though - using the specified `sizeof` values, **both calls will allocate 8 bytes.** (That is, `2 * sizeof(int)` which is `2 * 4`, and `sizeof(long)`, which is `1 * 8`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can always test your thesis with a some `printf` statements.  For your example, use:

```
    printf("\nsizeof int is %d, long is %d", sizeof(int), sizeof(long));
```

and you will see that: `2*sizeof(int) == 1*sizeof(long)`.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc doesn't`, but when you call `mem[0]` or `mem[1]` compilator knows what type is `mem` (`int *mem`) so when you're calling `mem[1]` it will know how much to increment `mem` pointer to access second element of this array. Distinction happens on compiler side.